# Fancybox examples: Where is Fancybox initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

On http://fancybox.net/ there are several examples of usage of FancyBox.

But In the code is has, for example, only

```
<li><a id="various3" href="/data/login.php">Ajax - passing custom data</a></li>
```

But I do not find any code that intializes the fancybox handling nor some class that marks a link as to be used for the fancybox.

So what is the clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the page include this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/web.js?m=20100203"></script>
```

here there is your answer:

EDIT:

```
$("#various3").fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : 'mydata=test'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See section 5 on this page: http://fancybox.net/howto

Apply Fancybox to the element with id `single_image` using all default settings:

```
$("#single_image").fancybox();
```

Apply Fancybox to all anchors with the class `group`, using 5 custom Fancybox settings:

```
$("a.group").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});
```

Comment: I was expecting such a thing but I can not fine any call to `.fancybox()` on the examples page.

Comment: Ctrl+F it for "various3", you'll see the fancybox call right away

Comment: thanks, that is a very stupid example, putting the relevant code to such an external file :-)